# Temporary Sticky Sidebar to avoid white space

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins, sidebar

We have some very long posts in a blog that I maintain. The sidebar however is not long enough for some posts that a lot of white space is visible as you read the posts. Also, our sidebar is not of the same height as the screens so a full sticky sidebar does not solve our problem.

We want to emulate the behavior of the sidebar of this site [Kayture.com](http://www.kayture.com/). The sidebar is long but it becomes temporarily sticky as you scroll down and near the bottom of the page. I've also seen that kayture runs on wordpress so if a plugin is out there, I hope someone can point it to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a Wordpress plugin for this stuff. Try something like StickyKit to make your sidebar fixed when reaching a certain point.

http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/